# Start window application from ssh

Tags: linux, forms, ssh, terminal, window

I'm connected to my Raspberry PI via SSH (Rasbian). Now I want to start an Application from it that uses a Graphical Interface. That Application is a simple Mono Window. It should be displayed on the PI's Display

I can't do it because it tells me that is has no DISPLAY set (thats true, since I use SSH)
When I'm starting it from the terminal app on the PI's Desktop it works as expected.

My querstion is now: What do I have to do, that I can start this app over SSH and the window pops up on the PI's desktop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to start the X application on the remote X server, see https://serverfault.com/questions/142244/how-do-i-start-a-x-application-on-remote-server-over-ssh

If you're trying to start the X application on the Pi, but show its window on your local desktop (you'll need X11 on your local desktop), use ssh -X.

Comment: Looks like I just didn't know the right search terms. Thanks alot!